# Google sheet onOpen() trigger is not triggered on mobile browser or mobile app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, triggers

I setup a trigger that run a function when the sheet was open, but the _onOpen trigger was triggered only I opened the sheet on PC browser, not mobile browser or mobile Google Sheet app.

Here how I setup the trigger:

[image]

Then, I tried to insert a simple trigger once more:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  _onOpen(e);
}
```

==> Not work too.

FYI, onEdit trigger still work perfectly on mobile.

How can I trigger the `_onOpen()` when a user opens the sheet on his mobile device?

Comment: What makes you think the trigger is not occurring

Comment: You can see what was triggered in real time here: https://script.google.com/home/executions

Comment: What is the `_onOpen()` function doing?

Comment: I recalculate/refresh some data at _onOpen()

Comment: @LuatNguyen-Neo.Mxn0 Can you post `_onOpen()`? There are some things that do not work with triggers and this could be the reason

Comment: my _onOpen fn is too long and be separated in multiple files. It did read the sheet data, do simple calculate new data then write back to the sheet. Your advice lights up sth in my head: I might create a very simple sheet with onOpen run hello-world to check if it can be triggered

Comment: @LuatNguyen-Neo.Mxn0 Are you having issues with a simple onOpen?